# Почему один и тот же проект в Android Studio, с одним и тем же кодом после сборки в apk имеет разный размер?

Tags: android, android-sdk, build, apk

Почему один и тот же проект в Android Studio, с одним и тем же кодом после сборки в apk имеет разный размер. Вчера вечером я билдил apk и он имел размер 7 мб., а сегодня уже 6 мб. Проблема ТОЧНО не связана с иконкой приложения или другими внутренними ресурсами.

Comment: С одним и тем же кодом? И вы 2 раза подряд нажимаете сборку и размер разный? Ой не верю.

Comment: код может быть один и тот-же, но вы могли поменять зависимости от других библиотек или изменить номер SDK

Comment: @Style-7 буквально ничего не менял в коде

Comment: @Andrey Mihalev необъяснимо, но факт

Comment: Если речь идёт о дебажной сборке через кнопку запуска, то она может быть инкрементальной. Студия экономит время сборки за счёт добавления изменённого кода в виде отдельного dex-файла без изменения остальных. При повторной сборке спустя время, или после чистки проекта - код будет пересобран и размер изменится. Ещё, если у зависимости указана версия с `+` или что-то типа `latest` - она обновится в любой момент без изменений в проекте с вашей стороны. Любое обновление любого плагина также может повлиять на размер кода.

Comment: @woesss спасибо, кажется я нашел ответ на свой вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Предпоследний комментарий - ответ на мой вопрос, спасибо

> Если речь идёт о дебажной сборке через кнопку запуска, то она может быть инкрементальной. Студия экономит время сборки за счёт добавления изменённого кода в виде отдельного dex-файла без изменения остальных. При повторной сборке спустя время, или после чистки проекта - код будет пересобран и размер изменится. Ещё, если у зависимости указана версия с `+` или что-то типа `latest` - она обновится в любой момент без изменений в проекте с вашей стороны. Любое обновление любого плагина также может повлиять на размер кода.